# What does makes resourceful do in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
make_resourceful do
    actions :new, :create, :show, :update
```

What is this doing?  It makes reading a controller pretty confusing for me.

Answer (score 2):

This code is stating that the actions that are handled by the controller are:

```
:new, :create, :show, :update
```

Answer (score 1):

The make_resourceful construct comes from a rails plugin that provides way to DRY up the controller code.

There is a complete screencast from Ryan Bates about the same - 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/92-make-resourceful

This is the best resource you can find. Happy coding.

Comment: Don't forget to dig in http://railscasts.com when you need any rails related information. Ryan also takes suggestions for the future screencasts.